# MongoDb C# driver throwing Serialization error in DateTime comparison

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime, comparison

I'm using C# driver for MongoDb. I have a very simple 'find' query:

```
var cursor = PortalContext.Users.Find(user => DateTime.Now > user.UpdatedDate);
return cursor.ToListAsync();
```

Throws an exception:

```
Message: "An error has occurred."
ExceptionMessage: "Unsupported filter: (8/13/2015 12:03:44 PM > Serialization(UpdatedDate))."
ExceptionType: "System.ArgumentException"
StackTrace: " at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.BuildFilter(Expression expression) at ...
```

Comment: Can you try to set `user.UpdatedDate` to a variable `updatedDate` and use it in the `Find` expression?

Comment: I mean, `PortalContext.Users.Find(user => DateTime.Now > updatedDate)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rearranging your `Find` so that the constant (`DateTime.Now`) is on the right hand side, does that work?

```
var cursor = PortalContext.Users.Find(user => user.UpdatedDate < DateTime.Now);
return cursor.ToListAsync();
```

There was a bug in the 1.x driver ([CSHARP-431](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-431)) where the driver didn't handle this scenario where the constant is on the left hand side. It was fixed a long time ago but this issue could be a regression of that.